# How can I access a specific variable of a function from another script?

Tags: python

I have implemented a code here using tensorflow to train a CSV file. This works without any problems.

```
# training.py 

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

def trainingTS():
    df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')
    X = pd.get_dummies(df.drop(['Fire'], axis=1))
    y = df['Fire']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

    model = Sequential()
    model = tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam())
    model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
    model.save('my_model.h5')
    
    return model
```

Now to my current problem. I need the variable `model` in another python file `publish.py`.

```
#main.py

from training.py import trainingTS

def finallyVisual():

    model = trainingTS()
    model.load_weights('my_model.h5')
    # ...
```

To do this, I simply called the Python `training.py` method `trainingTS()`. But when I run the python file `main.py`, the complete python file of `training.py` is executed. How can I access this one variable `model` without outputting the complete function? I am currently still a beginner and do not know how to execute this. Implementing the variable `model` outside of the function is not possible, because I need the finished or trained `model` version.

Comment: Where are you importing `Sequential()` can you add that line also?

Comment: can you return your model in `finallyVisual`? is that possible?

Comment: Ive edited it above. Sequentiel is imported from tensorflow.keras.

Comment: my finallyVisual() is showing my opencv webcam. Unfortunatley i cant return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation after saving you can use `.load_model('path/to/location')`.

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize

---

```
#main.py

#from training.py import trainingTS
from tensorflow import keras

def finallyVisual():

    #model = trainingTS()
    model = keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')
    model.load_weights('my_model.h5')
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks ive implemented your solution and its perfectly working.

Comment: @maramaku Then make sure to mark it as the correct answer